# Fortigate VM Logs

Tags: fortinet, fortigate

I have a Fortigate VM v5.2.0
I have setup VPN like described here [Fortigate IPsec VPN for iOS](http://docs.fortinet.com/d/fortigate-video-configuring-an-ipsec-vpn-for-ios-devices)

I can logon with iOS and I see in Local Traffic Log the connection:

**[Pic1](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3672/kww5etys_png.htm)**

But when I try to browse a denied website I don't see any blocked traffic and I don't see any traffic in Forward Traffic.
I can generate Test Traffic for Forward Traffic over `ssh` and traffic shows up in log:

[Pic2](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3672/bmrzgb8t_png)

All Logs are enabled:

[image: Pic3]

I don't really understand why i can't see single connection that are allowed or denied for my vpn device

Comment: [Pic2](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3672/bmrzgb8t_png.htm)

Comment: [Pic3](http://s14.directupload.net/images/140703/8hicghyu.png)

Comment: would you please log on via console and post your configs for the VPN tunnel and the policy allowing the traffic out to Internet?

Comment: [VPN](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3672/g6woazh6_png.htm) I'm not very familiar with fortigat cli, i haven't found policy on cli

Comment: [VPN Gui](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3672/qbn5e3os_png.htm)

Comment: [Policy](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3672/mipomd59_png.htm)

Comment: [Policy Overview](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3672/5zmr9hoz_png.htm) I have also added a second ineterface and created a policyso i can oibg from one vlan to other vlan, this is working and it's logged, So i guess something with VPN Configuration is wrong